# jquery ajax does not send request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the following code.

```
var sendJson = (JSON.stringify(comanda));

$.ajax({
    url: 'sendMail.php',
    type : "post",
    data: sendJson,
    success: function(data){
        alert("Comanda dumneavoastra a fost trimisa");
    }
});
```

Seems like data is not sent.... any idea why?

Ok... I know nothing is sent because I monitor requests with firebug.
I get no errors, nothing in console. Checked if it is activated, it is.

Comment: what errors are you getting? Add an `error` callback and will can get more info on the actual error..

Comment: That's the problem. No errors.

Comment: Also, try using fiddler to see what requests are sent. www.fiddlertool.com

Comment: Have you inspected network traffic in your browser's developer tools? or are you just flying by the ear on the absence of an alert?

Comment: can you add an **`error` callback**?

Comment: Let's rephrase the question: what indications do you see that this is not working?

Comment: firebug net tab and console is empty... how do i add the error callback?

Comment: after `success: function(data){ alert("Comanda dumneavoastra a fost trimisa");}` just add `,error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /* implementation goes here */ }`. Then set a breakpoint and see what happens..

Comment: K... added callback and found the problem. It was a bad uri... although I usualy got the bad uri from fbug also. Ty for help... post as answer so I can accept pls.

Comment: you can add one yourself I guess..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I meant with my comment:

```
var sendJson = (JSON.stringify(comanda));

$.ajax({
    url: '/resource_url_goes_here',
    type : 'POST',
    data: sendJson,
    success: function(data){
        /* implementation goes here */ 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        /* implementation goes here */ 
    }
});
```

Note that the ajax request has an `error` callback now. All requests should have an error callback so you can easily identify when errors are happening (as you've seen, firebug doesn't catch everything).

Another thing that I find helpful sometimes is `StatusCodes`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/resource_url_goes_here',
    type : 'POST',
    data: sendJson,
    statusCode: {  
        404: function() {  
            /*implementation for HTTP Status 404 (Not Found) goes here*/
        },
        401: function() {  
            /*implementation for HTTP Status 401 (Unauthorized) goes here*/
        } 
    },
    success: function(data){
        /* implementation goes here */ 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        /* implementation goes here */ 
    }
});
```

This will execute a function when a specific status code is returned by the server (404 and 401 in this snippet) and you can have a specific handler for the status codes you need.
You can find more about this [here](http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes).